# Admin Grid Form Fields Side-by-side

Tags: admin, adminhtml, css, grid

I have a form that looks like this:

[image]

But I'd like it to look like this (fields side-by-side instead of on top of one another):

[image]

How can I do this?

If you're interested in the code, here is an example field in Module/Block/Adminhtml/Sqlreport/Edit/Form.php:

```
$fieldset->addField("column_description", 'text', array(
    'name'      => 'column_description',
    'label'     => 'Description',
    'class'     => 'sqlreport_column_description',
));
```

Comment: As per Magneto Standard It will not achive. But if you want to developed this thing then you have to must handle using your Custom CSS

Answer (score 1):

It is mostly CSS related question. 
You can do this if you have a parent class of this form, or if you have a specific class for every of this columns.

In example for a specific classe's of these columns!

- Checkbox Entity has a class **.sqlreport_column_entity**
- Description has a class **.sqlreport_column_description**
- Header has a class **.sqlreport_column_header**

Now in CSS files you'd have to style all above classes with

```
.sqlreport_column_* {
float:left;
}
```

And all other styling that would be necessary.